# Como configurar o xampp para aceitar o comando openssl_pkey_new?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, openssl, httpd

Estou tentando utilizar o comando openssl_pkey_new, ele estava funcionando muito bem no wamp, mas ao usar o xampp ele parou.

O código esta desta forma:

```
$sslConfig = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA            
);

$privkey = openssl_pkey_new($sslConfig);
```

O erro que esta apresentando é este:

> ```
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> ```

Todas as pesquisas que fiz apontaram que o erro esta no arquivo openssl.cnf, mas eu já tentei de tudo para funcionar e ate agora não obtive um resultado positivo apenas o mesmo erro acima.

Setei o caminho do arquivo no httpd-xampp.conf, todos que encontrei na pasta do xampp, tentei também o que eu tinha na pasta do wamp, tentei ate instalar o openssl no windows e setar o openssl.cnf dele e também não funcionou(Tentei ate colocar o openssl nas variáveis de ambiente só pra "desencargo de consciência").

Tentei adicionar o caminho também utilizando o config no próprio php, desta forma:

```
$sslConfig = array(
    "config" => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Carteira\openssl.cnf',
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => $tamanho,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA            
);
```

E o resultado continua o mesmo, ao printar o comando getenv('OPENSSL_CONF') mostra o caminho que configurei no httpd-xampp.conf, colocando ou não no $sslConfig:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Carteira\openssl.cnf
```

Verifiquei se o caminho estava correto diversas vezes, inclusive utilizei o comando file_exists, para ter 100% de certeza, e sim o caminho esta certo, ele retorna 1.

```
echo file_exists(getenv('OPENSSL_CONF'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queria utilizar o xampp porque gostei do seu desempenho, achei ele mais rápido e mais fácil de configurar em comparação com o wamp, mas acabei desistindo e voltei para o wamp, porque durante todo o projeto eu usei ele e não tive problema.

De fato no xampp o comando openssl_pkey_new não estava funcionando, então através de pesquisas descobrir este comando:

```
while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    echo $msg . "<br />\n";
```

Ele serve para mostrar os erros do openssl, porem ao instalar o wamp novamente e rodar a aplicação, me deparo com o mesmo erro encontrado no xampp (Não utilizei anteriormente o comando openssl_error_string no wamp, já que não tive problemas ao utilizar o openssl no wamp):

> ```
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value
> ```

Achei estranho, já que fiz os mesmo procedimentos da ultima instalação, então ao pesquisar mais um pouco, descobrir que o comando openssl_error_string não deve ser utilizado desta forma, dentro de um while e sim desta forma:

```
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new($sslConfig);
openssl_error_string();
```

Ou seja o comando e logo abaixo o openssl_error_string(), assim ele captura o erro daquela execução, utilizando while ele vai gerar erro, já que não conseguiu pegar nenhuma "segunda" execução.

Então é possível que ao configurar o caminho correto do openssl.cnf ou ao colocar no config o caminho, o problema foi solucionado, mas agora estou utilizando o wamp de novo, então não posso afirma.